# PostgreSQL ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, where-clause

i have to create a simple view in Postgres but somthing goes wrong.

i will paste my SQL query below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW domotica."sensori-stanze-unita"
 AS
SELECT
sens.id_sens,sens.nome,sens.id_stanza,stanz.id,stanz.id_immobile,immo.id
FROM domotica.sensori AS sens
INNER JOIN domotica.stanze AS stanz
INNER JOIN domotica.immobili AS immo
ON stanz.id_immobile = immo.id 
WHERE sens.id_stanza = stanz.id;
```

The error displayed is the following

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 9: WHERE sens.id_stanza = stanz.id;
^
```

Comment: Your first `JOIN` doesn't have a  join condition (it's missing the `ON` clause)

Comment: Please for code questions give a [mre]. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. PS We can expect this is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN`  requires a `ON` clause, that usually contains the join conditions. Here, you can just move the conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the first join:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW domotica."sensori-stanze-unita" AS
SELECT se.id_sens, se.nome, se.id_stanza, st.id AS st_id, st.id_immobile, im.id as im_id
FROM domotica.sensori AS se
INNER JOIN domotica.stanze AS st ON se.id_stanza = st.id
INNER JOIN domotica.immobili AS im ON st.id_immobile = im.id
```

Comment: how can i rename one of my id column ?
because i got this error now
ERROR: column "id" specified more than once

Comment: i can do something like im.id AS id_im ?